# Adding kSOAP dependency to Gradle project

Tags: android, maven, gradle, ksoap2

I'm trying to make kSOAP working in my Android project with Gradle.

This is my project's build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:12.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.0.0'
}
```

The library seems to be included in the project and compilation DOES work but when I try to import a class (ie SoapObject) it seems like the namespace does not even exist. The funny thing is that the other libraries (such as ACRA or Guava) are working fine. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This can be a problem with android studio (I asume you use one). Did you try to write a code (that uses kSOAP) and then building the project from commandline?

Comment: I did and it did not compile at all. It tells me "error: package org.ksoap2.serialization does not exist" on the import and "error: cannot find symbol" on the first SoapObject variable definition.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This took me a bit to figure out as well, but I have finally gotten it working. I've been working on a WSDL parser that parses for KSoap and finally got that working only to fight through Gradle with the import of ksoap. At anyrate here is how you do it.

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
        classpath 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'

}
```

Of course mine is a service library, so you may want to use apply plugin: 'android'.
Hopefully this helps and saves somebody some time.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I got it working with Gradle. It took me some time to fix it but now it works.

Comment: Not working for me, it compiles but won't run on my device 'ClassNotFoundException' so I'm back with jar file ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar, I don't know if it is because of dependencies (don't think so because it's the maven's power) ... Thanks anyway for sharing this ;)

Comment: actually      compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'
    dont work!

Answer (score 49):

I am using @amitav13's solution but the URL of the repository has changed:

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases' }
    }
```

Current version as of now is 3.6.0

```
compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'
```

This did work for me.

Answer (score 35):

Here's a more minimal version of the build.gradle suggested by Sam that works for me:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases' }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2'
}
```

Note that this is the app's build.gradle, I have not made any modifications to the project build.gradle.

Comment: @amitav13, do you still need the .jar file for your example to work? if not you could probably do without the line 'compile fileTree(...) right?

Comment: @Brabbeldas no I don't. I left that in there since this was the the default generated build file, plus the code to get kSoap working.

Comment: @amitav13  Thank you. After few hours of struggle and trying every other answer this is the one that worked! But the repository address is changed. you should update that :)

Answer (score 14):

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}
```

and inside Dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same situation. And I gave up to add that jar from mavencentral.

I added the raw jar as a lib.

1. Download the latest (or whatever version) of ksoap2-android from
   [this url](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/#ksoap2-android-assembly/3.1.1)
2. Call it in the build.gradle, see below

Here is the code:

```
dependencies {
   compile files('libs/ksoap2-android.jar')
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: I totally gave up on Gradle instead. For small projects it's an overkill!

Comment: @AxelGeNuS, yea. I was in the same situation. But It is really efficient even it is for small project. You should try it again when you got some free time. :)

Answer (score 3):

These answers are pretty old and none of them worked for me. Here is my solution using Android Studio 3.1.4 and ksoap 3.6.4

android gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.aspservicetest"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases' }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.4'
}
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me once I deleted  the pre-existing copy of the ksoap jar file from my /libs/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

More simple solution is just download the .jar from http://www.bvbcode.com/code/ed5zc936-1814251-down and add this .jar file to your libs folder.

Finally in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') 
}
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are already answers using a jar file.  I wanted to add one with the latest updated links:

[Download ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/3.6.4/) and add it to folder libs.

in build.grade:

```
android {
...
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
        }
    }
}
...
dependencies {
...
 implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
...
}
```