# Generation of APK fails due to httpcomponents:httpclient conflict warning

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

```
**Build.gradle**:-
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    lintOptions {
        // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        quiet true
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
        // if true, only report errors
        ignoreWarnings true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.org.mobility"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.6.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1'

}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your `build.gradle` code

Comment: @1911192110920: Can you post your `build.gradle` for your app module here?

Comment: May be this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460148/dependency-ignored-because-of-conflict-android-studio

Comment: Not this, `build.gradle(app)` share that file

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have imported this in your app gradle file

```
android {
..
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, you have to edit code as below

```
android {
    .....
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
  }
}
```

Add above code inside android tag. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried this also but no luck. by the way thanks for your support.

Comment: What is actual problem you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your gradle to exclude the conflicts

```
compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1' {
exclude module: 'httpclient' 
exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' 
exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
```

}

Comment: its showing new warning like Warning:library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser.

Comment: Could not find method com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1() for arguments [build_bp7i02jonpi9yt3yo241ty8qf$_run_closure2$_closure10@3f7a69a3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Comment: This page might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774355/adding-ksoap-dependency-to-gradle-project

Comment: But want to minifyEnabled should be true.

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude httpclient in your build.gradle. Paste the code below in your build,gradle and rebuild. The warning should go away.

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}
```

Here is how the build looks after excluding the httpclient module
[image]