# Android ClassDefFoundError while trying to send byte array using ksoap

Tags: android, arrays, base64, ksoap

I am developing an android app, in which I am converting an image to byte array and sending it using ksoap2. When I am trying it I am getting an exception and the app is getting crashed. I am giving my code and stacktrace below..If any one can help me .. please help.

**log**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.kobjects.base64.Base64
>   at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.MarshalBase64.writeInstance(MarshalBase64.java:39)
>   at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:653)
>   at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:645)
>   at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:614)
>   at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:598)
>   at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:655)
>   at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:579)
>   at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:192)
>   at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:82)
>   at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:79) 
>   at
>   com.example.manappuram.punching_maceinn.MainActivity.GetConfirm(MainActivity.java:420)
>   at
>   com.example.manappuram.punching_maceinn.MainActivity$10.onPictureTaken(MainActivity.java:797)
>   at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:823)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

MainActivity

```
public void GetConfirm() {
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/cccc";
        String METHOD_NAME = "ccccc";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        String URL = "http://zxxxx.xx.xx.xx/my_services/ccc.asmx";

        try {

            //Code added by Jocheved on 31/03/2017
            String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/JCG Camera/img.jpg";

File imagefile = new File(photoPath);
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi1.setName("xcode");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(empId.getText().toString().trim());
            pi1.setValue(x);
            pi1.setType(Integer.class);
            Request.addProperty(pi1);

            pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi2.setName("in_time");
            pi2.setValue(shiftTime.getText().toString().trim());
            pi2.setType(String.class);
            Request.addProperty(pi2);

            pi3 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi3.setName("em_id");
            pi3.setValue(3531);
            pi3.setType(Integer.class);
            Request.addProperty(pi3);

            pi4 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi4.setName("photo_rel");
            System.out.println("image convertion string is " + img);
            pi4.setValue(b);            
            Request.addProperty(pi4);

            pi5 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi5.setName("ipd");
            pi5.setValue("10.29.245.85~DT-3501-56070");
            pi5.setType(String.class);
            Request.addProperty(pi5);


            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            new MarshalBase64().register(soapEnvelope);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transport.debug = true;
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            System.out.println("Cannot serialize 1");
            try{
                SoapObject result=(SoapObject)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(result!= null){
                    System.out.println("Resp in confirm click is " + result.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')    
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'    
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/org-apache-commons-codec.jar')

}
```

Comment: You don't need 2 `compile files(...)`, because `compile fileTree(...)` does that.

Comment: So how I need to change it..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were not added ksoup library properly.that's why gradle is unable to find it.

Can you please check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774355/adding-ksoap-dependency-to-gradle-project)

**Edited:**

Don't add library from lib.Try to copy and paste below line into build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'
```