# Ksoap2 Library to android studio Error message, how to fix?

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I an trying to import Ksoap2 library in android studio using .jar file version 3.6.4. I have successfully implemented the jar file to android studio. However, on the module app activity when I try to import e.g. import "org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;", it gets and error it shows following results:

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.4.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/3.6.4/ksoap2-android-3.6.4.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/3.6.4/ksoap2-android-3.6.4.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/3.6.4/ksoap2-android-3.6.4.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Also the imports library have error, please see the pic:
[image]

Here is the Build.gradle module code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is Build.gradle(app) Module code:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kowloondairycompanykdl.milk_ic"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation files('libs\\ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.4'

}
```

Please help me, I been stuck here for a long time. How to fix the error and how can I implement the Ksoap2 library properly. Thanks

Comment: Problem solved! Just used this as reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774355/adding-ksoap-dependency-to-gradle-project/56821715#56821715](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774355/adding-ksoap-dependency-to-gradle-project/56821715#56821715)

Comment: Just a side note use `implementation` instead of `compile` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a 3.4.3 version of that library.  There's a 3.4.0.  And the newest is 3.6.4.  You're going to need to use one of those.  I'd move to 3.6.4 as 3.4.0 is over 5 years old, and likely lacks security updates.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, it suppose to be 3.6.4. I fixed, and there is still error. Please help me

Comment: How come I cannot import the KSoap2 ??? Im so stuck, Im looking at many solution but i seem to not find, please anyone please help??

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dependencyResolutionManagement block from the setting.gradle file to have your project work the old way.

Related issue: [Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69163511/build-was-configured-to-prefer-settings-repositories-over-project-repositories-b)