# Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

Tags: android, gradle

I want to add jitpack.io as a repository in my gradle file.
This is my gradle root file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"

        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Since I DON'T have a "allrepositories" to put my dependency there (only works there), I've created and added this code after buildscript code:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {url 'https://www.jitpack.io'}
    }
}
```

But this is the error I get

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
```

Answer (score 484, accepted):

### General Info

Gradle 6.8 introduced [central declaration of repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/release-notes.html#dependency-management-improvements), new way to define repositories. Latest documentation (7.4.2) [can be found here](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration).

*You have 2 options from here;*

### Remove central declaration to work with your current config

For this you need to remove the `dependencyResolutionManagement` block from the `setting.gradle` file (=the new way). And then the `repositories` config in your `build.gradle` will work again (=the old way).

build.gradle *(no change from your example)*

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {url 'https://www.jitpack.io'}
    }
}
```

### Update to work the new way

The way forward is to edit `build.gradle` removing that `repositories` declaration. And then edit `settings.gradle` to include the maven config.

settings.gradle

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I also had to remove "testImplementation 'junit:junit:'" from build.gradle

Comment: great..now i have some new errors - `Could not find androidx.databinding:viewbinding:7.0.3.` and also in some other code segments like `paypal` related code and other also

Comment: This worked well. Just want to know why did they do this ? Any specific importance of dependencyResolutionManagement in settings.gradle?

Comment: Where u were Bro.... ? i was wondering this solution from last 3 days..... Thanks Brother... u r a life saver...

Comment: thanks for the tip. 
but why did that in the first place ?

Comment: You might face the same issue @VivekThummar and I did after you get rid of the block. That is because with the new way of declaring repositories the `allprojects` block in the project build.gradle file is not included. You will have to add it to the file so the project knows where to find dependencies.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Or you can set `repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)`

Comment: Gradle loves changing things like it's a high fashion brand when they're a build tool where inertia is valued

Comment: Great answer with both old and new examples. That makes life a lot easier when you have inherited a 5 year old codebase. Searching for android info is frustrating because google will point you to old and outdated info.

Comment: It is possible that 'settings.gradle' already has that repositories, so you could just delete old declaration of repositories and it will work

Comment: For Kotlin use the following sintax: maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }

Comment: mmh @Kunami why not just `maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")`?

Answer (score 284):

You can add **jitpack.io** as a repository inside **dependencyResolutionManagement** in settings.gradle

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is better than the accepted answer imo, it uses the new system instead of disabling it.

Comment: this is better than accepted answer. and working ofc

Comment: maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }

Answer (score 111):

You need to update the settings in `settings.gradle` and change `repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)` to `repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)`

and finally, add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to the repositories block.

The complete `settings.gradle` file will look like this:

```
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

dependencyResolutionManagement { 
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories { 
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "appname"
include ':app'
```

Comment: PREFER_SETTINGS only makes sense if you want to ignore declarations in project instead of getting the error. If you want to move them FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS is better, I think.

Answer (score 75):

Replace this line:

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

**use this:**

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
```

### **Before**

[image]

### **After**

[image]

```
  repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
```

Comment: Thanks @lava It works just add target & compile SDK version 33.

Answer (score 23):

Go To Settings.gradle and put it inside the repositories

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

In `gradle version '7.1.0'` just need to add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in `setting.gradle`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

***Solution:***

You can add this url
in **settings.gradle(Project Settings)** file,
which you will find in **Gradle Scripts**,

Add your url inside **dependencyResolutionManagement** like this

```
dependencyResolutionManagement{
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }    
}
```

#See below pic for complete reference,
[image]

Now sync it,
it will work,

Thank you!
:)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I just delete the `dependencyResolutionManagement{...}` statement that in the `settings.gradle` the new project is default added in settings.gradle

Answer (score 5):

if you access repository secured by login/password - try this

here example based on GitHub repo

```
<settings.gradle file>


groovy

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY")
            credentials {
                username = "${usernameFromYourGradlePropertiesFile}"
                password = "${passwordFromYourGradlePropertiesFile}"
            }
        }
    }
}


kotlin

// ...
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY")

            val userNamePropertyFromGradleProperties: String by settings
            val passwordPropertyFromGradleProperties: String by settings

            credentials {
                username = userNamePropertyFromGradleProperties
                password = passwordPropertyFromGradleProperties
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

**As the Android studio is upadated so you have to control your dependency form your setting.app**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
```

} rootProject.name = "EmfDetector"
include ':app'

**Kindly place this line the respiratory**

```
      maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } //as i have done above 
     `
```

Answer (score 3):

You either could delete the

```
dependencyResolutionManagement{}
```

block in the

> setting.gradle

file and then add the repositories in the

> build.gradle

at Project Level as, for example

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
} }
```

or write a repository directly in the

```
dependencyResolutionManagement{}
```

block. Don't forget to Sync the Project by clicking top-right on

> Sync now

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in settings.gradle

[See more information here](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32273912)

Answer (score 1):

add it to your settings.gradle inside dependency resolution management like this:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

some old advices let you add maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }into root build.gradle, but as long as you are using latest version of as, you can simply put it into settings.gradle instead of build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just add mavenLocal() in settings.gradle

Answer (score 0):

remove everything from repositories. It helped me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are here because android studio says to you that you have to add a `;` but doesn't work anything solution for you, so this did works for me and I hope can help you to resolve the problem

Well, I put `mavenLocal()` in this file -> `settings.gradle`

[image: Structure of my project]

This is how I set my file

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
  }
}
```

Now, press `Sync` and this should be working