# Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'app/build.gradle'

Tags: android, gradle

I initially had a problem like the one below and I made a post

> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

then the post of the problem was closed because there was already a familiar problem, with the highest rated answer as below (update gradle)

[answer url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)

> **Latest Gradle: 6.5**
>
> Version check:
> ./gradlew -v
>
> **How to update**:
>
> Set URL: ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.5 --distribution-type=all
>
> Update: ./gradlew wrapper

but I don't have a **gradlew** file, then I took the initiative to create a new project and I took the **gradlew** file, **settings.gradle** file along with the **gradle** folder, then I ran the command from the answer above, but stuck in the command (in the Set URL version I use 7.2, because when creating a new project the gradle version is the default)

```
./gradlew wrapper
```

the command raises an error

> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'app/build.gradle'

then I tried to find a solution, and I got a similar question and there was an answer that was ticked in green as below

[answer url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69163511/build-was-configured-to-prefer-settings-repositories-over-project-repositories-b)

> Android introduced a new way to define repositories.

> Remove the dependencyResolutionManagement block from the setting.gradle file to have your project work the old way.

but after i removed the dependencyResolutionManagement block from setting.gradle i got the same problem at the beginning i.e

> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

the following is the contents of the settings.gradle file before I delete the dependencyResolutionManagement block

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application6"
include ':app'
```

below is the contents of the settings.gradle file after I removed the dependencyResolutionManagement block

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
} 

rootProject.name = "My Application6"
include ':app'
```

note: when an error appeared the last time I tried, rootProject.name was not the same as the current project

Comment: The Gradle version should be 7.2 and don't declare the repositories twice; the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, So what should I do because I always get into trouble, and the problem revolves there