# Error adding KMM to existing Android Application

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I created one simple Android Application using Kotlin and Android Studio. I did one API integration using Ktor.

Till this part, everything is working fine.

For adding Kmm, I simply added a new KMM module using Android Studio Wizard.
Now when I try to integrate KMM into this existing project, I am getting an error.

> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project
> respositories but repository 'ivy' was added by build file
> 'shared/build.gradle.kts'.

I checked the gradle file but there was nothing named 'ivy' in that. I also tried few related solutions available but none helped.

Comment: it doesn't sounds like KMM specific. have you checked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69163511/3585796)?