# The Gradle For AdMob

Tags: android, gradle

[Edit below as the answer from @fillobotto almost solves my problem]

I am following the docs page from google [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start).

In various post here on StackOverflow it says I need to put my `buildscript` and `allprojects` before `plugins`. So I have updated my gradle to the following (the new bits are the `buildscript`, `allprojects` and `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'`):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cmg.www.cmg"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1022
        versionName "1.022"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def billing_version = "6.0.1"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"

    /* This is for adverts */
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    /* This for ImmutableList */
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-android'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

But, the following error occurs when compiling:

```
Could not compile build file 'C:\wamp64\www\cmg\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\wamp64\www\cmg\app\build.gradle': 14: only buildscript {}, pluginManagement {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed
```

Where should these new sections go?

**Edit made due to @fillobotto answer:**

I have removed the `buildscripts` and `allprojects` from the module level gradle.

Instead due to @fillobotto answer I have put them in the project level `build.gradle`

However, in my project level gradle I already have the lines

```
plugins {
    id   com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
```

So I need the `buildscripts` and `allprojects` to work around that.

I can put the `buildscript` section in before the `plugins` without problems.

However, if I put the `allprojects` section in before the plugins section, ie

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
plugins {
    id   com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
```

it says I cannot put `allprojects` in before plugins.

If I put `allprojects` afterwards, ie:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
plugins {
    id   com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I get an error saying

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project.
```

If I leave the allprojects section out altogether, ie

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
plugins {
    id   com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
```

it appears to build and sync fine, but I have not checked the adverts are working properly yet. I will try to see tomorrow.

Edit 2:

On further advice I have removed the `plugins` section from my project gradle, so the **project** gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

However, when I sync it still dislikes the `google()` in the `allprojects` section, giving the error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'CMG'.
> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'CMG'.
    ......
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
```

Comment: The `plugins{}` should be in the app module level gradle build file, so you can safely remove project level's one. However, those two lines have the `apply false` parameter which should make them completely useless. Remove the whole plugins block from there and resync project

Comment: Thanks again @fillobotto for the help. I have tried what you said, but I still get an error when I sync. (Its Edit 2 in my OP).

Comment: Never saw this error before. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71186329/1950812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the first step of the guide you linked, the edits need to be done inside the **project-level** `build.gradle`. The one you pasted is the **app module** `build.script` though.

The correct file is located in the root directory of your project, for example:

```
C:\user\documents\myproject\build.gradle
```

You should edit the file so it looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Also, you should remove the code you added from your app module `build.gradle`, except for the `implementation` line which should still remain under app module's `dependencies`

Comment: This is true except for the `implementation` line, which should be in the app level grade file (as also stated in the linked instructions)

Comment: In the project level `build.gradle` I already have the lines `plugins {id 
 com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false }`. I can put the `buildscript` section in before without problems. However, if i put the `allprojects` section in before the `plugins` section, it say I cannot put that in before `plugins`. If I put it afterwards I get an error saying `org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project`. If I leave the `allprojects` section out altogether, it appears to build and sync fine.

Comment: @Rewind please update the OP and paste code there

Comment: Thanks for the reply @fillobotto. I have updated as requested.